# Weird string return from firebase storage url image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

i've put down some code to upload image to my firebase storage and then retrive the url to use it to show the image as a profile pic for my application android.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("ProfilePic", filepath.toString());


                db.collection("Accounts").document(user.getUid())
                        .set(data, SetOptions.merge())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                            }
                        });


            }
        });
    }
}
```

with the filepath variable, i use it to save the url of my image into the database inside the account folder. So every pic has a unique profile reference.

The problem is the return value of filepath. It shows the path inside firebase for example

```
gs://eyesee-gd23b.appspot.com/image/44405857
```

so i try to use

```
filepath.getDownloadUrl()
```

but instead of the url that i can see it on firebase webpage, i retrieve something like

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@dsd873
```

any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase manual states this:

> `getDownloadUrl() : Task<Uri>` : Asynchronously retrieves a long lived download URL with a revokable token.

Key word is asynchronously. You get it in much the same way as you get result from `filepath.putFile(uri)`, by setting an `onSuccessListener` or `onCompleteListener`. Or loop `filepath.getDownloadUrl().getResult()` until it returns a result, but that's just not right.

`onSuccessListener` calls `onSuccess(Uri result)`, which you override and do with result as you wish directly. Only called if task didn't fail. Otherwise you'd want an `onFailureListener` too.

`onCompleteListener` calls `onComplete(Task<Uri> thisTask)` which you can check for failure and get result with `thistask.getResult()`.